# How to send state.data.length from one component to different component in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a simple list which has a edit and delete functionalities. Now I'm thinking to make a pi chart out of the data of list.

What I'm struggling is to pass the data of list length in one component to another component to make a pi chart.

How can I pass this kind of data from one component to another one?

List.js

This is a List.js file. I want to pass `this.state.questionItem.length` to another component in another file.

```
const questionItem = [ { item : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor?', id : 1
}, { item : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor?', id : 2
}, { item : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor?', id : 3
}, { item : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor?', id : 4
}
]

export default class List extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        questionItem
    };
}

createItem(item){
    this.state.questionItem.unshift({
        item : item,
    });
    this.setState({
        questionItem : this.state.questionItem
    });
    console.log(this.state.questionItem.length)
}

findItem(item) {
    return this.state.questionItem.filter((element) => element.item === item)[0];
}

toggleComplete(item){
    let selectedItem = this.findItem(item);
    selectedItem.completed = !selectedItem.completed;
    this.setState({ questionItem : this.state.questionItem });
}

saveItem(oldItem, newItem) {
    let selectedItem = this.findItem(oldItem);
    selectedItem.item = newItem;
    this.setState({ questionItem : this.state.questionItem });
    }

deleteItem(item) {
    let index = this.state.questionItem.map(element => element.item).indexOf(item);
    this.state.questionItem.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({ questionItem : this.state.questionItem });
}

render() {
    return (
    <div className="list" style={{"display" : "flex"}}>
    <div className="titleElement" style={{"flex": "1", "backgroundColor" : "orange"}}>Advice + FAQ </div>
    <div style={{"flex": "5", "display": "flex", "flex-direction": "column"}}>
    <QuestionList questionItem={this.state.questionItem} deleteItem={this.deleteItem.bind(this)}  saveItem={this.saveItem.bind(this)} toggleComplete={this.toggleComplete.bind(this)} />
    <CreateItem questionItem={this.state.questionItem} createItem={this.createItem.bind(this)} />
    </div>
     </div>);
}
```

Chart.js

```
class Categories extends React.Component{
{ I want to receive the data of item length here } 
render(){
    return(<div>
          <div id="chart" >
              <p> pi chart comes hire</p>
          </div>
          <List />
          </div>
          </div>
    )
}
```

Thank you for your help in advance..!!

Comment: React Redux will help you

Comment: @Sergey Is it possible to do this without Redux?

Comment: It's the best way for this. It's concentrated point for all the states of React app which makes it easy to update the whole state of app.

Comment: Also it's not really hard. So I would recommend you to learn it. It's a really useful feature. In Angular it also is.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. This time I don't use it but I'm sure to learn Redux very soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure wheter I got your point or not, but if you want to send `this.state.questionItem.length` to your chart:

If this is not your case, please let me know so I remove the answer :)

```js
class Chart extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { length } = this.props
    
    return (
      <div>Chart: {length}</div>
    )
  }
}

class List extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      questionItem: [
        {
          item: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur',
          id: 1
        },
        {
          item: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur',
          id: 2
        },
        {
          item: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur',
          id: 3
        },
        {
          item: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur',
          id: 4
        },
      ],
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    const { questionItem } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <Chart length={questionItem.length} />
      </div>
    )
  }
} 

ReactDOM.render(<List />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry but my explanation was not sufficient. I updated my question. I already have `questionItem` in List.js. I want to pass the length of questionItem to Chart.js..

Comment: @ayumi It's exactly what I have on my answer. `List` passes the `length` to Chart. Please check again

Comment: @ayumi Can you render `Chart` through `List` or not?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. It worked perfectly. Thank you.